# monitor service and restart if stop using icinga

Tags: debian, services, monitoring

I am using [icinga](https://www.icinga.org/) to monitor services in my system. It will give stats and reports regarding services.

I want to know that, is there any way to ask `icinga` to restart service if it stops. For example, if `icinga` monitors `apache2` service. If someone stops `apache2` then `icinga` try to restart `apache2`. After 5 attempts if its not starts, it will report `Unable to start service`.